What are those bars in subway train or bus called?
What are those bars in subway train or bus that allow standing passengers to grab to stabilize themselves during trips called? Are those horizontal overhead or waist-height bars (with or without straps) and vertical bars/poles called the same?

The long ones, whether vertical or horizontal, can all be called grab rails, and the shorter ones are often called 'grab handles'.

This question has been discussed here: What is that loop you hold on to...?

@MichaelHarvey do you mean straps by grab handles?

Strap loops hang from grab bars.

@MichaelHarvey which does "grab handles" mean, strap loops, or grab bars?

@Tim It depends on the material. If it's a strap, it's called a strap. If it's metal, hard plastic, or similar, it's a handle.

These are often called grab rails

Grab poles are vertical...

Grab handles hang down from rails that people can also grab

if they are made out of strap material, they may be called grab straps, hanging straps, or strap handles...


That last item leads to the common expression for the riders of the subway: strap-hangers.

Personally, I call them "hand rails". I have never heard the term "grab rail", but I am European.
Interestingly the company that  manufactures them also calls them "hand rails" (or handrails in another section of the paragraph!)


The pic I showed above of 'grab rail coatings' showed a British train (a Bombardier Electrostar).
